# How to create package in Java EE application using Eclipse

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I have created a new Java EE project using Eclipse. But when I'm trying to create a new package inside the project I'm getting an error message like "Source folder does not exists".

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should create your packaging inside a folder src/main/java then maybe some part like your jsp or template inside the src/main/webapp folder.

With eclipse you should use maven with some archetype depending on your needs, you can easily create a full webapp like this.

You might right click on src and click on "Build Path / Remove from build path" depending on your needs. then you packaging should be inside this src file, you might check with you explorer if some folder exist inside your src folder

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to create maven web app project.After creating webapp project by using below command.You can create new packages..

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId={project-packaging} -DartifactId={project-name} -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false.
```

Comment: I am not using the maven web app project.

Comment: Is it a webapplication you created.